# .htaccess gives 500 error on localhost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

i'm beginner to MVC framework. I'm trying to create one my own based on tutorials.

.htaccess file that they provide contains:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA, L]
```

i get 500 server error:  The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

I checked httpd.conf to check if mode_rewrite was not commented. Can anyone help me please? i'm using LAMPP on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Check your Apache error log. It's probably in `/var/log/apache/`

Comment: Just shooting... Apache module `mod_rewrite` is disabled on your server

Comment: mod_rewrite is not disabled it does not have # in front of it on httpd.conf, how can i enable then

Comment: If it's enbaled go look somewhere else. As ascii-time said check your logs

Comment: im using ubuntu so cd /var/log/apache gives me no file found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA, L]
```

Changed to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Note, "[QSA, L]" vs. [QSA,L]

Duplicated your error, removed space, worked). I'm using WAMP.

Comment: thank you now idont get error but for some reason my Bootstrap does not see $_GET['url'] it says undefined index

Comment: never mind i had an error in php file. It was Index.php for controller and in my bootstrap it was looking for lowercase index.php so i just made it so that it makes first letter capital and now it works. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try cjriii's answer and if that doesn't work, check the AllowOverride variable in the httpd.conf file and make sure it says All and not None.  That tripped me up the first time I started working with mod_rewrite too.