# localhost showing 500 internal server error

Tags: php, localhost, port

Localhost showing 500 internal server error after changing port from 80 to 81.

I have configured project in IDE(Zend Studio).

I am seeing this:

> **Internal Server Error**
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform
>   them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done
>   that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

I am unable to understand this error as other projects on my system are working but when import any project in Zend Studio it shows above error.

Comment: usually in `/var/log/apache2/` you can check the log. you can use `ls -ltr` inside the directory to get the latest log files at the bottom of the list

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess gives 500 error on localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232907/htaccess-gives-500-error-on-localhost)

Answer (score 0):

- There might be several reasons which can cause 500 Internal Server Error.

  1. A Permissions Error-In most cases, a 500 Internal Server Error is due    to an incorrect permission on one or more files or folders.
  2. A PHP    Timeout-If your script connects to external resources and    those    resources timeout, an HTTP 500 error can occur.
  3. A Coding Error in .htaccess - While not as common, be sure to check    that your site's    .htaccess file is properly structured.
- Try the following methods.Hope one of this might work.

  1. Try refreshing the web page(you can use f5 key or ctrl+r)
  2. Clear browser cache.
  3. Delete browser cookies and restart the browser.
  4. Troubleshoot as a 504 Gateway Timeout error instead.( It's not very common, but some servers produce a 500 Internal Server Error when in reality 504 Gateway Timeout is a more appropriate message based on the cause of the problem.)